# Нужна помощь jquery, php, css с select option

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, css, mysql

Нужна помощь в конструкции, вообщем я сделал на сайте регистрацию где есть страна/регион/город (регион и город только для России). Сейчас выбор работает, но, не полноценно,а тоесть, Если выбрать Россию то показывает блок регионов, затем городов (вроде все хорошо, но), если пользователь указал уже все данные, **в профиле не получается их вывести**, нужно что бы было как на картинке
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/sh/i5ku2ld65c774bo/WYYsnHt4qV/example.png]

Я пытался по всякому делать, вытаскивал с функций, совмещал функции, и все равно не выводит как нужно.

Здесь файлы с базой стран / регионов и городов России, а так же файл `ajax_city.php` в котором обрабатывается информация, и `main.php` где я занес все остальное, jquery и css.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i5ku2ld65c774bo/JgAqFXTnbK

В файле `main.php` если заменить `$user_country = "0"; на $user_country = "3159";` , то результат будет как раз такой, на который я ищу решение.

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Таких решений в инете масса:

http://webersoft.ru/svyazannye-s-pomoschyu-ajax-selecty-jquery/

http://xandeadx.ru/blog/javascript/36

это только на вскидку...

Comment: мне не нужны готовые решения, мне нужно только направление, и решений на первый взгляд много, но все не то, либо написано слишком длинным кодом, либо не на Jquery.

Comment: @Nazaret2005 направление такое - получив id страны отправляйте его php (например $.post('countries.php',regionList,"json")), чтобы он нашел список регионов и городов. возвращайте в виде json,  как получите ответ, показывайте второй select (и третий, если есть) и вставляйте в него полученные опции. всё.

Comment: @eicto проблема в том, что для того что бы jquery обработал запрос, нужно выполнить POST/GET, если в <select> стоит id=0 и я выбираю что то, то отправляет и получаю нужный результат, но когда изначально уже указан id страны, то действие POST не отправляется и тем самым не выводит регионы. Вот тут и проблема, не знаю как быть даже.

Comment: У Вас на каждый селект должен происходить вызов функции (например на onChange) с вызовом ajax, и в принудительную отправлять нужные вам данные в обработчик.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте AJAX.

```
var $selectCountry = $('select[name="country"]')
  , $selectRegion = $('select[name="region"]').hide()
  , $selectCity = $('select[name="city"]').hide();

$selectCountry.change(function(){

 $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/getRegions.php',
  data: {
    countryId : $(this).val()  //код страны
  },
  success: function(regions){
    //строим список регионов
    var options = '';
    for(i = 0, region; region = regions[i]; i++){
       options += '<option val="' + region.id + '">' + region.title + '</otion>';
    }
    $selectCity.html(options).show();
  }
 })
});

$selectRegion.change(function(){
   //подгрузить города выбранного региона
});
```

Пример `getRegions.php`

```
<?php

# данные для подключения к MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

# подключаемся к базе
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
# проверяем соединение
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

# получить все регионы нужной страны и отсортировать их в алфавитном порядке
$countryId = isset($_POST['countryId']) ? $_POST['countryId'] : null;
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM regions WHERE country_id = " . $countryId . " ORDER BY title";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

#собираем регионы в массив
$regions = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $regions[] = $row;
}

# не забываем отключиться от базы
$conn->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json; carset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($regions);
```

По аналогии с этим примером тебе не составить труда создать свой обработчик для подгрузки городов при выборе региона